# ASP.NET MVC2 View Model for multiple view forms and data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, model, view

one thing that has been puzzling me since learning MVC2 is the following case scenario:

I have a view which contains two latest news lists, a login form and a signup form.

Every example I found on Views and View Models so far has a one-to-one example such as a simple login form etc. But how do I create a model that provides the properties and validation for a login and signup form and manages the data for the news lists.

Can I pass multiple models in the strongly typed view?

When I created one model the form validation would fail as it expects all fields - login and signup to be filled.

I am missing some advanced examples or information. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I usualy create .ascx in this case.

I make ascx strongly typed for the model (in your case LoginModel)
I make a second ascx strongly typed (in your case SignupModel).

Then I make aspx and put those 2 ascx-es inside of it <% Html.RenderPartial("Login", Model.Login); %> and similar for the other one.

And you make aspx also stronly typed as

```
class PageModel
{
   public LoginModel Login { get; set; }
   public SignupModel Signup { get; set; }
}
```